# Bundle install Jquery-rails taking too long to respond from gemcutter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hi guys the gem jquery-rails(0.2.7) cant seem to be installed on my machine saying there are too many connections and it times out, I know this is not actualy programming but it is a fundamental for any ROR programmer esp in rails 3, so i'm actually looking for any1 who might have came across this error and resolved it. The error is as follows.

> /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:365:in `request': too many connection resets (http://production.cf.rubygems.org/gems/libxml-ruby-1.1.4.gem) (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:289:in`open_uri_or_path'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:298:in `open_uri_or_path'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:172:in`fetch_path'
>           from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:110:in `download'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in`download_gem_from_uri'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:76:in `fetch'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:45:in`run'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in`each'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in`install'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:217:in `install'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in`send'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in`invoke_task'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in`start'
>           from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/bin/bundle:13
>           from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
>           from /usr/bin/bundle:19

Thanks in advance
~D

Comment: for any1 who might exp this, The problem was the unstable internet connection cause now it just installed it perfectly..kip on tryin and u wil get it right. :)

Comment: sorry. I saw your comment after posting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a connection issue. Try running the command again will install the gem.